# Cannot hover or select grid row after store.sync() call

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

After calling `store.add(newRecord);` a new row is added to the grid and I can select/hover/deselect it, but after calling `store.sync()` to save that row to DB, it cannot be selected/hovered/deselected anymore.

These actions only work after reloading the page (F5) or calling `store.reload()`

How I can fix it? I don't want to use reload.

Comment: Is this an ExtJS or Sencha Touch issue? What version?

Comment: @Guiherme Lopes: I use ExtJS 6.2.0

Comment: The only reason I can see for select/hover/deselect stop working is if when you call `store.sync()` you are hitting a JavaScript error. Are you getting any messages in your console.log?

Comment: I found what is happen. Before sync(), I add a record which have id like this: "MyApp.model.MyModel.MyModel-2". And store save that id to lookup when it need. But after sync(), that record is change to '238' (id auto generate in my database). And the store can't look up my new id